# Get Current windows users-at Client side

Tags: node.js, windows

Index.js file is not returning the Client user id- who is accessing the Index.js, instead its returning server user id where Node.js is installed.

Node.js is installed on the windows server 2012

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var userName = process.env['USERPROFILE'].split(path.sep)[2];
var loginId = path.join("domainName",userName);
console.log(loginId);

http.createServer(function (req, res) 
{
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

res.end('Hello :-) '+userName);
}).listen(3000);
```

when any user access the index.js file, it should return the userid.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you can use express framework( easiest way) . 
but if you want to stick to nodejs basic structure, then you can use this

```
request.connection.remoteAddress
```